# Quartz and spring scheduler is different?

Tags: spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I am not sure whether I am asking correct question or not.

Is Quartz (`org.springframework.scheduling.quartz`) and spring scheduler(`org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;`) is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are different. 
TaskExecutor is a spring abstraction, while Quartz is an implementation of the Spring Abstraction using Quartz Scheduler.

See more details on spring documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling

Comment: Ohh Thnaks :). Which one is more better to use.

Comment: If you wanna use a Scheduled task on your spring application, see the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling